# Force svn update after commit

Tags: svn

Somewhat related to https://serverfault.com/questions/380286/svn-info-shows-old-revision-as-the-current-revision, how can I force SVN to update my working copy immediately after I've committed it? Essentially, I'd like my svn info to always be current, since I attach that information to my executables when I send them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not "force" `svn up` after `svn ci`. But you can

- Use always `svn ci && svn up` as shell-alias
- Always commit from WC-root, not from deep subdirectory (avoid mixed-WC)
- Use not output of `svn info`|`svninfo` on deploy, but results of subwcrev|svnrev